# Qual algoritmo de compressão pode ser baseado em dados antigos e reconstruir dados usando a apenas a diferenças entre eles?

Tags: compressão

Estou pensando em criar um pequeno jogo. O jogo é "executado" no servidor, e o cliente apenas "exibe as imagens", baseado no estado do jogo. Conside que, o estado do jogo é uma lista de elementos, de jogadores (...). Por exemplo, cada jogador pode ter um nome, uma quantidade de vida (...), uma ferramenta/arma (...) e ele também está numa posição especifica (...).

Sendo assim, assumindo que o servidor enviaria todas as informações a cada 32ms, acredito que haveria um gargalo. Dependo da quantidade de players/objetos.

---

Uma alternativa ao envio de "todo o estado do jogo" a cada frame, seria de enviar a diferença entre o frame anterior e o novo. Mas, fazer isso também iria exigir que o cliente entendesse diversos eventos diferentes. Não acredito que isso seja viável. O servidor já codifica tudo para Flatbuffers, e o cliente lê a informação e exibe. Então, uma alternativa que pensei, seria, em nível de bytes, enviar apenas aquilo que foi alterado.

Num primeiro frame, enviamos o estado do jogo:

```
0x00 0x10 0x12 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0xDE 0xF0, 0x10 ...
```

*Digamos que isto representa um array contendo o estado de todos os players, e que no total isto tenha ~10MB. Isto será enviado para o cliente.*

Se o próximo frame (após 32ms) for enviado:

```
0x00 0x10 0x12 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0xDE 0xD1, 0x10 ...
```

Supondo que a única mudança é o `0xD1` no offset de 9. Então, se o cliente já tem o estado antigo, ele poderia simplesmente receber algo como `0x09 0x01 0xD1`. Isso é: Na posição 9, com tamanho 1, troque por `0xD1` (estou assumindo uint8 para simplificar). Lógico que isso poderia ser mais complexo, para aproveitar deslocações e repetições.

Nessa ideia, a quantida de dados transferidos seria muito menor, e melhor ainda: não exigiria o cliente entender comandos especificos, e poderia ser retrocompativel (já que o Flatbuffers é retrocompativel).

Dessa forma, ao invés de enviar 10MB todo frame, que é inviável, poderia apenas enviar instruções de como atualizar o dado antigo para o novo.

---

**O nome desta tecnica é mesmo "compressão" ou existe algum outro nome especifico?**

**Existe algum algoritmo de compressão que funciona desta forma (que envie apenas instruções para criar o dado novo, usando modificações num dado anterior)?**

Eu procurei por LZW, ZSTD (...), mas todos eles parecem comprimir apenas o dado atual, e nunca se basear numa informação já existente, pelo menos as APIs padrões.

Talvez, seria possível usar o LZZ de forma que o "buffer" (há outro nome para isso) dele já estivesse preenchido com os dados antigo, antes de comprimi-lo, dessa forma ele poderia substuir aquilo que fosse igual. Mas, é isto o mais eficiente? Ele não me parece ter sido desenvolvido para isso.

Comment: Aparentemente o dessa tecnica é "delta encoding".

Comment: Veja se contribui [Streaming Lossless Data
Compression Algorithm](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-321_1st_edition_june_2001.pdf)

Comment: Sugestão (sem conhecer o gameplay): definir o estado em um dicionário indexado por números (no client e server), e atribuir prioridades a cada item. Os itens mais críticos que precisam de atualização rápida, tem prioridade maior. Exemplo: a posição do jogador no índice 0, disparo de arma no 1, etc. Itens de menor prioridade, como inventário, objetos, diálogos, etc. você atualiza de forma assíncrona, sem gerar dependência no framerate. Exemplo de atualização: uma posição relativa + 2 estados (index+vec3+s1+s2) , pode ser enviada em um qword de 64 bits (idx:8bits, s1,s2:1bit, pos:3*18bits).